# Graph of $7\cos x+5\sin x=2k+1$

Tags: trigonometry

The question is to find the number of integral values of k for which the equation $7\cos x+5\sin x=2k+1$ has a solution.

I have solved it by converting the LHS into $\sqrt{74}\sin (x+\alpha)$, where $\alpha= \arctan(7/5)$. And then making an inequality with RHS.

But I wonder how to solve this question graphically.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $a\sin x+b \cos x$ in a form $A\sin (x+\phi)$ where $$A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
In your case $A= \sqrt{74}<9$, so $|2k+1|\leq 7$...

Comment: I already solved like this!

Comment: Ok, so how can I help you? You wanted a comfirmation? Or you want me to delte it or something else?

Comment: I was wondering how to solve it graphically. Like, making two graphs,one of LHS, and one of RHS. And then superimposing them to see the number of solutions. I have solved other questions like this, but couldn't solve this one.

Comment: Why would you do it like that? It is much harder. You are trying to go from Paris to London via New York...

Comment: Ok, I see your point. One last thing. Shouldn't we say 2k+1 is less than or equal to 8, instead of 7?

Comment: $2k+1$ is odd, so it can be at most 7 and not 8

Comment: ok, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write the left-hand side as
$$\sqrt{74}\left(\frac{7}{\sqrt{74}}\cos(x)+\frac{5}{\sqrt{74}}\sin(x)\right)$$
so
$$\sin(\phi)=\frac{7}{\sqrt{74}}$$
$$\cos(\phi)=\frac{5}{\sqrt{74}}$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: I already solved like this!